# php data rearrangement help - multidimensional array needed? Help please

Tags: php, mysql

:)

I have 6 arrays that are coming out of a MySQL db. There is no definitive length to how much data will be in these arrays, but it is very safe to assume that they will not exceed up to 40 pieces of data each. In each case, the respective arrays will always hold the same amount of data, so if the first array holds 4 values then the remaining arrays will also hold 4 values each. I am extracting them and holding them in a single master array (perhaps not the correct term?) like this:

```
$Spoon = array(
$rtd = explode(" ^ ", $reg_travel_date),
$rtf = explode(" ^ ", $reg_travel_from),
$rtt = explode(" ^ ", $reg_travel_to),
$rkt = explode(" ^ ", $reg_kms_travelled),
$etct = explode(" ^ ", $exp_type_car_travel),
$rck = explode(" ^ ", $reg_claimable_kms),
);
```

Now I would like to know how to manipulate this info so that I can get the values to display in a foreach output that will result in a count being taken of how many values there are and then display them in something like this:

```
<tr style="background: <?=cycleColours()?>">
 <td><strong><?=$rtd?></strong></td>
 <td><strong><?=$rtf?></strong></td>
 <td><strong><?=$rtt?></strong></td>
 <td><strong><?=$rkt?></strong></td>
 <td><strong><?=$etct?></strong></td>
 <td><strong><?=$rck?></strong></td>
</tr>
```

Of course I need that to cycle until all of the values in the selected arrays are displayed, then to stop. I am sure this should be fairly straight forward but I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to rearrange the data to end up with this result. Some PHP help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of those things you're exploding all result in arrays with the SAME number of elements, then you just need a loop:

```
foreach($rtd as $key => $val) {
   echo <<<EOL
<td><strong>{$val}</strong></td>
<td><strong>{$rtf[$key]}</strong></td>
<td><strong>{$rtt[$key]}</strong></td>
etc...
EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, that was far more simple than I was expecting. Your help is very much appreciated. :)